# QueryDsl JPA using subquery in from clause

Tags: jpa, spring-data, querydsl

is it possible in QueryDsl to perform a subquery in the from clause?

I would like to do something like:

SELECT * FROM

(Select Ammount, Ammount*(.10) as TenPercent From Expense)

Where TenPercent > 1

The general problem I am trying to solve is using a field from the projection (in this case TenPercent and PlusTenPerceent) in the where clause which can only be solved by using subqueries in the from clause.

How do you express this in QueryDsl? JPAExpressions do not solve this because it can not be used in the JPAQuery.from() method.

Any input is welcome!